# How can I use my Android partitions for Windows?

Tags: partitioning, filesystems, android-x86, ext

I have a dual-boot Android/Windows mini PC.

How can I make I use the Android partitions for Windows, without breaking the Android to much?

(I have external disks, but there are some things like SWAP that cant be external, also Windows update etc often need some space)
[image]

Comment: As they're using different file systems you probably won't be able to do much. You might be able to find a Ext3 driver for Windows, at least for Ext2 there was one available.

Comment: I imagine I could format them, if I was sure I could reverse it.

Answer (score 0):

The Android phone I have at hand uses ext4fs for most of its partitions, so an ext4fs driver for Windows might do the trick. There are drivers for this, but I haven't used any of them in over a decade (since before ext4fs was released, in fact). Ones I found when Googling are:

- [Paragon's driver](http://www.paragon-drivers.com/extfs-windows/)
- [The Ext2Fsd driver](http://www.ext2fsd.com/)
- [The DiskInternals reader,](http://www.diskinternals.com/linux-reader/) which provides read-only access via a special program
- [Ext2Read](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/) is another read-only tool

The last two of these probably wouldn't suit your needs, since they're read-only. As I said, I've not used any of these recently, so I can't comment on how good they are. There might be others that my initial Google search didn't reveal.

Comment: If I can read the disks, and verify that there is nothing critical, I could "Downgrade" to Fat*, and it might even work for Android.

Comment: As we can see there are only 2 partitions with a bit of space, so I think I should either keep partitions and look at those, or find a way to backup and restore several partitions in one go.

Comment: Do not try to convert an ext4fs partition to FAT on an Android device! If Android has set up a partition as ext4fs, chances are it needs features present in ext4fs that aren't provided by FAT, such as Unix-style ownership and permissions. There may well be exceptions to this rule, but unless you have a very deep understanding of Android, you're more likely to create problems than solve them by changing the filesystem used on a partition.